# wrong listview gets deleted in baseadapter inspite of correct position

Tags: android, list, listview, arraylist, baseadapter

I am trying to delete a listview item from my custom base adapter. Here is my code.

```
@Override 
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) 
{ 
    infoList.remove(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}
```

My list view is embedded in a SwipeRefreshLayout.
The last item of the listview always gets deleted because the wrong item in the List infoList get deleted even why the right position is passed to it.

Comment: One should not be deleting stuff in the getView method of the Adapter. Please show more code like the Adapter and Fragment/Activity classes.

Comment: Am not using a recycler view. Am using a listview with a custom base adapter. I first remove the item from the list then I notifyDataSetChange. Wrong utem it removed from the list view. Read my code.

Comment: @Saret I can't perform adapter.remove(object) within the base adapter class itself. and how do I get th variable object

Comment: @Saret you seem to have no idea about what am talking about

Comment: What @NarayanAcharya said is correct. You should not be removing items from the getView() method. It is called when the list view needs another row created in which to display your next item. Calling notifyDataSetChanged()  may lead to more subsequent calls of getView() and strange behaviour. If you want to remove rows from your list view, move those lines of code to a different method. Also make sure you have implemented the adapters getCount() so when you call notifyDataSetChanged() the adapter will detect that you have less items and will refresh your list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was not set the visibility of all elements in the view to GONE, set all paddings and margins of the view elements to 0. After successful deletion in mysql db, listview item disappears. This was done in the custom adapter class.